# If I want my textarea to be hidden, how do I do it?

Tags: html, css

If I want my textarea to be hidden, how do I do it?

Answer (score 36):

Everyone is giving you answers, but not much on the reasons. Here you go: if you use the CSS rule `visibility:hidden;` the text area will be invisible, but it will still take up space. If you use the CSS rule `display:none;` the textarea will be hidden *and* it won't reserve space on the screen—no gaps, in other words, where it would have been. Visual example below.

So you want something like this to be *totally* hidden:

```
<textarea cols="20" rows="20" style="display:none;">
```

---

### Example

```css
/* no styling should show up for either method */
textarea {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p><strong>Textarea (not hidden)</strong></p>
<textarea>Text within.</textarea>
<p>Some text after.</p>

<hr />

<p><strong>Textarea with <code>display:none;</code></strong></p>
<textarea style="display:none;">Text within.</textarea>
<p>Some text after. Neither height nor margin/padding/layout kept. No other styles visible.</p>

<hr />

<p><strong>Textarea with <code>visibility:hidden;</code></strong></p>
<textarea style="visibility:hidden;">Text within.</textarea>
<p>Some text after. Height and margin/padding/layout kept. No other styles visible.</p>
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a few options, here are some examples:

1. Display:none
2. Visibility:hidden

Here is some example code for you to see for yourself

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Text Area Hidden</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hideButTakeUpSpace
        {
            visibility: hidden;
        }

        .hideDontTakeUpSpace
        {
            display:none;
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Text area hidden examples</h1>
    <h2>Hide but take up space (notice the gap below)</h2>
    <textarea class="hideButTakeUpSpace" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>

    <h2>Hide Don't take up space</h2>
    <textarea class="hideDontTakeUpSpace" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>


</body>
</html>
```

See this [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rY9Xg/)

Answer (score 4):

Using css: `display: none;` (this will make the textarea disappear completely, the space it would normally take up will not be reserved)

Comment: i have this code 
<textarea name=text cols=20 rows=10>
how do i set this to be hidden

Comment: You could add style="display: none". As @thelost says, you could also do style="visibility: hidden". This will make the textarea still take up space on the page. You should really put this in a style sheet. That would mean adding class="hidden" to your textarea-tag and adding textarea.hidden { display: none; } to your css file

Answer (score 4):

Hidden with occupy the space on current webpage.

```
<textarea style="visibility:hidden"></textarea>
```

Disappear on current webpage with no other effect.

```
<textarea style="display:none" ></textarea>
```

Comment: How can i then select the text in that textarea. Like if i want to select the text that is in that textarea the selcet() method is not working.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
textarea.none {
    display: none;
}

textarea.hidden {
     visibility: hidden
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<textarea class="none">The display is none.</textarea>
<br>
<textarea class="hidden">visiblity is hidden</textarea>
<br>
<textarea >This is visible and you can see a space taken visiblity:hidden</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the CSS visibility property should do the trick.